# MYSQL SELECT with COUNT, FROM, WHERE, GROUP BY

Tags: php, mysql, select, count, group-by

I'm having trouble adding a where clause to this query. I would like it to select from where the column 'SAT AM/SUN PM' is 'yes' AND where the column 'confirmed' is 'yes'.

This works without the 'WHERE shift_times='SAT AM/SUN PM'-- it's not outputting anything with this:

```
        $query = "SELECT position, COUNT(confirmed) FROM volConfirm WHERE shift_times='SAT AM/SUN PM' GROUP BY position"; 

    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

    // Print out result
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        echo "There are ". $row['COUNT(confirmed)'] ." ". $row['position'] ." " . $row['shift_times'] . " volunteers.";
        echo "<br />";
```

A LITTLE MORE INFO: 
The table contains records that are either confirmed with 'yes' or '0'(for no) and the shift_times are either SAT AM/SUN PM or SAT PM/SUN AM. There are several different positions. I am trying to display the final results like so-ish:

There are: "30" "Art" volunteers for "SAT AM/SUN PM"

There are: "30" "Art" volunteers for "SAT PM/SUN AM"

Ideally the rows would rotate so the echo under that would be the inverse data for "SAT PM/SUN AM"- but that seems a bit trickier...

Comment: is SAT AM/SUN PM a column in your query you are using it as a value in the column

Comment: No, SAT AM/SUN (as well as SAT PM/SUN AM) are options in a column called 'shift_times'

Comment: Under the column shift_times, there are two possible values in the record- some are SAT AM/SUN PM and some are SAT PM/SUN AM.

Comment: have you tried it in phpmyadmin to see if there are any errors

Comment: Thanks COLD TOLD. That helped me see where I didn't have all the SAT AM/SUN PM spaced the same (some had a space between / SUN, others didn't)

Comment: Any idea on how to echo the SAT AM/SUN PM- and vice versa under each other, as in the OP? Right now I just have each in their own column.

Comment: you mean another echo for  SAT PM/SUN AM info

Comment: Yep- I have no clue how to set this up...right now I have two completely separate columns w/ their own php mysql_query connections

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I changed your select statement to select and group by the shift times,  so one row would be selected per position,  per shift time.
I added an alias of 'cnt' to your count() and updated the php to use cnt in the echo statement
No closing bracket at the end of your while loop (could be a copy and paste issue)

```
$query = "SELECT COUNT(confirmed) as cnt
          , position
          , shift_times 
         FROM volConfirm 
         WHERE confirmed='yes'  
         GROUP BY shift_times, position
         order by shift_times, position"; 

$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

// Print out result
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo "There are ". $row['cnt'] ." ". $row['position'] ." " . $row['shift_times'] . " volunteers.";
    echo "<br />";
}
```

Comment: I'm still learning mysql and the AS was on the list to learn- and that order by is new to me in this form-- thanks! This is a great piece to study off of---

Comment: Hold the mayo-- it's not doing as I'd hoped, with the SAT AM/SUN PM (1) and SAT PM/SUN AM(2) for each position displayed in rows on top of each other-I'm actually looking for results like Art=1,2 Bar=1,2 Merch=1,2 etc. But the above is getting the job done for me visually.

Comment: Solved! I simply changed "order by shift_times, position" to  "order by position"-- thanks again!

Comment: Hello Michael, I got an similar question, could you please take a look?